# Replace values in a 2D array with different random numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I have a 2D array (image) in which I want to replace array values greater than some threshold with a random number in some range. My attempt was to use numpy.random.uniform, as so

```
Z[Z > some_value] = uniform(lower_limit,upper_limit)
```

However I've found that this replaces all values above the threshold with the same random value.  I would like to replace all array values above the threshold with a different random value each.

I think this would require some interation over the entire array for which I would need to generate a random value if the condition is met.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that iteration would be the correct way to go. Let's do a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

```
[uniform(lower_limit, upper_limit) if i > some_value else i
 for i in Z]
```

Let's step through it. Take an individual value. If it is greater than the threshold, use a randomly generated one, otherwise the original value.

```
uniform(lower_limit, upper_limit) if i > some_value else i
```

Repeat this for every element in Z

```
for i in Z
```

For a 2D array, nest multiple comprehensions. Imagine that the above solution was to hit everything in one row and then repeat it for every row.

```
[[uniform(lower_limit, upper_limit) if i > some_value else i
  for i in row]
  for row in Z]
```

Comment: After implementing this I am getting the error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.`  I'm guessing this is because it is a 2d array? Is there a way to iterate using the above list comprehension and preserve the shape of the array (2d) without having to convert it to a 1d array?

Comment: @maelstromscientist My apologies, updated with new example. Iterating (using a list comprehension of course) over each 1D array in your 2D array should work for you.

Comment: Nevermind, I had a silly mistake with variable names and once that was fixed it worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: Huh. No idea. It may be time to split the offending piece of code out. `def small_or_random(num): ...` then simplify the comprehension to `[[small_or_random(i) for i in row] for row in Z]`. That should be much easier to debug / reason about.

Comment: @maelstromscientist You should start to get used to the mechanisms provided by numpy to work with whole arrays at once instead of doing operations element-wise by looping or using list-comprehensions. It is advantageous both in terms of speed and readability. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the third argument to `uniform`. Using `size=N` will yield an array of random values with length `N`. Thus

```
z[z>some_value] = np.random.uniform(lower, upper, len(z>some_value))
```

will do what you want.